# Finding if a piecewise function is differentiable

Tags: derivatives

Im trying to find if f(x) is differentiable for any value of m.

$$   f(x) =
\begin{cases}
3x^2 + mx - 1,  & x \le 1 \\
2x+3, & x>1
\end{cases}$$

Do I check for continuity?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Do you mean differentiable at $x=1$?  It's differentiable everywhere else.  Continuity is a necessary but not sufficient condition for differentiability.  You'll need more.

Comment: Checking for continuity is easy and a good start.  If it is not continuous then it won't be differentiable.  However, it is not sufficient, it may be continuous but not differentuable.  So, having found the case(s) in which it is continuous, you need to look further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ is continuous iff $m=3$.  But it can’t obviously be differentiable for that $m$.

Comment: So I can correctly say that f is not differentiable for any value of m?

Comment: That’s definitely right.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ will be continuous iff $$ \lim_{x\to 1_{-}} (3x^2 + mx - 1)=\lim_{x\to 1_{+}}
(2x+3)$$ so
$$ 3+m-1 = 2+3\implies m= 3$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1035361)

Comment: Yes? And the other answer does? @Louis

Comment: It does neither, but it wasn't in the review queue... - Edit: and technically it answers the question; although it doesn't give a proof for the stated claim. (Which is straightforward)

Comment: While the Question would be narrowly read as asking about continuity, the title and other content specifies an issue of differentiability.  So if you want to give a useful Answer, a response for both continuity and differentiability is needed.